# Is there any decoupled PHP-binding or PHP implementation for twitter bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, implementation

I was just wondering if there are **decoupled** implementations in PHP for the twitter bootstrap Framework?
I found a boundle in laravel http://bootstrapper.aws.af.cm/components

but that is too tightly integrated with laravel.

Is there any library which I'm missing right now through github / google search, before I start building my own?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of offer a decoupled approach and integration with Twitter Bootstrap. I currently develop on Bootstrap and use PHP Template Inheritance (http://phpti.com/) for my templating engine. You could start there and then look for the other CMS components you need.